# JSON JAXB Object type serialization

Tags: json, jaxb, cxf, jettison, badgerfish

I'm trying to serialize JSON via JAXB using CXF. The problem is when the element to transform is a Object type.

```
@XmlElement(name = "Value")
    protected Object value;
```

the result in JSON format is

```
"Value":{"@xsi.type":"xs:string","$":"LED"}}
```

Any idea how I do to transform in simple json format?

```
"Value":"LED" o r "Value":1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have enabled [BadgerFish](http://badgerfish.ning.com/) notation for your Jettison converter (I am not aware about BadgerFish notation support in [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Which_mappings_.28Badgerfish.2C_natural.2C_....29_does_Jackson_implement.3F) or [MOXy](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html)).

If you use JBoss [`@BadgerFish`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jettison-provider/2.3.2.Final/org/jboss/resteasy/annotations/providers/jaxb/json/BadgerFish.java#BadgerFish) annotation, just remove it. If you use [`JSONJAXBContext#BADGERFISH`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.12/com/sun/jersey/api/json/JSONJAXBContext.java#86) option setting, then change it to `MAPPED` or `NATURAL` ([check documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#d4e949)).

Answer (score 0):

Set `writesiType=false` in `JSONProvider` Bean configuration